# WPF user control inheritance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a WPF control in a library project and would like to extend it with a new one.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.ExtensionUtils85.GUI.EmbeddingUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have tried to extend it like this:

```
<src:EmbeddingUserControl x:Class="Interaxalab.Desktop.Modules.PrototipoCable.CustomViews.InteractionView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.ExtensionUtils85.GUI"
    Name="InteractionWorksheetView" Height="321.613" Width="471.396"
>
    <Grid>

        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="windowsFormsHost1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="284" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="471"/>

    </Grid>
</src:EmbeddingUserControl>
```

However, I get an error message saying that the name "EmbeddingUserControl" does not exist in namespace "Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.ExtensionUtils85.GUI".

The name clearly does exist, since the xaml.cs can find it, but for some reason the xaml cannot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short - you cannot inherit control with xaml by another control with xaml (and does it makes sense even to do so?). In your case, EmbeddingUserControl does not contain any visual tree elements (just empty grid), so you can just do:

```
public class EmbeddingUserControl : UserControl {
    // some methods, properties of your control
}
```

Then you can inherit exactly like you do already in your question (don't forget to inherit from EmbeddingUserControl **both** in xaml file and in code-behind file).

You can also inherit from user control with xaml, if your inherited control does not have xaml itself (so you can add\override logic).

If you need to inherit some visual stuctures - you have to switch from inheritance to composition. That is: your base control provides some placeholders where other controls may be placed, or even better allows to provide templates to format data items (like for example ItemsControl and ItemTemplate property). Then you just fill those placeholders with other controls if necessary.